# Get date in milliseconds (long) for upcoming Saturday

Tags: android, date, datetime

In my app, I want to show the list of appointments that a User has in this week. The arguments to be passed to the API are fromDate and toDate in milliseconds (long). I need to know how can I get the date in milliseconds of the last day of the week (Consider the week starts from Sunday and ends on Saturday).

Answer (score 0):

```
   // get today and clear time of day
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // ! clear would not reset the hour of day !
        cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
        cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

// get start of this week in milliseconds
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println("Start of this week:       " + cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("... in milliseconds:      " + cal.getTimeInMillis());

// start of the next week
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
        System.out.println("Start of the next week:   " + cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("... in milliseconds:      " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

for the last day of week add 6 there !!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding first day of week as Sunday and then add 6 days to it.

```
// Get current time. You can reset hours/ minutes/ seconds it with default values which you want. 
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.getDefault());

// Set first day of week
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);       
// Add 6 into that to get Saurday
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);

// Get millisenconds for Saturday
long millies = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Yes. It will do by using 'Locale.getDefault()'. And if you want to get country specific then you can use 'Locale.US' or 'Locale.CANADA' etc

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code to get the upcoming saturday in milliseconds.

```
public class NextSaturdayMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(getSaturday(new Date()));
    }

    public static long getSaturday(Date today) 
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.setTime(today);

        int dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        while (dow != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            int date = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);

            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            if (date == getMonthLastDate(month, year)) {

                if (month == Calendar.DECEMBER) {
                    month = Calendar.JANUARY;

                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);
                } else {
                    month++;
                }

                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);

                date = 1;
            } else {
                date++;
            }

            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date);

            dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        }
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
        return cal.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private static int getMonthLastDate(int month, int year)
    {
        switch (month)
        {
            case Calendar.JANUARY:
            case Calendar.MARCH:
            case Calendar.MAY:
            case Calendar.JULY:
            case Calendar.AUGUST:
            case Calendar.OCTOBER:
            case Calendar.DECEMBER:
                return 31;

            case Calendar.APRIL:
            case Calendar.JUNE:
            case Calendar.SEPTEMBER:
            case Calendar.NOVEMBER:
                return 30;

            default:    //  Calendar.FEBRUARY
                return year % 4 == 0 ? 29 : 28;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have removed the link to your website as it doesn't add anything more than what's posted here. Please read [Is it acceptable to promote your own blog?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273209/is-it-acceptable-to-promote-your-own-blog) and [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)